# Why to print a string in interrupt driven IO, only the first character needs to be copied?

Tags: io, operating-system, driver, interrupt

Almost all materials I found online referenced the code below from Tananbaum's OS book. However I don't really understand why this would print the whole string instead of only the first character.

Is it because the interrupts will be generated recursively? But wouldn't that cost a lot of resources? Or did I miss something?

I'm really confused. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Code executed when print system call is made:

```
copy_from_user (buffer, p, count);
enable_interrupts ();
while (*printer_status_reg !=READY);
*printer_data_register = p[0];
scheduler ();
```

Interrupt handler:

```
if (count == 0) {
  unblock_user ();
} else {
  *printer_data_register = p[i];
  count = count – 1;
  i++;
}
acknowledge_interrupt ();
return_from_interrupt ();
```

Comment: If not already transferring data, transmit interrupts need to be'primed' by explicitly loading the tx register with the first byte.   Unless you do that, there wil be no 'tx register empty' interrupts to send the rest of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write first character in buffer and start the transmission.
After completion of transmission, `Tx_Complete` interrupt will be generated.

Now, your interrupt handler checks, whether there are any more bytes to transfer (The `else` part). If available, it adds next byte to transmit register, decrements number of bytes to transmit and increments buffer index.

This process goes on... When number of bytes to transmit reaches zero, you don't initiate next transfer and your interrupts stop.

By transferring first byte, you initiate the process and rest bytes are transferred by interrupt handler. You have to make sure that `count` is correct.
You can guess what can happen if count is less or more!